# How do users control permissions of Timeline actions that are published?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, privacy

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/, the 'Default Activity Privacy' field in the Auth Dialogue can only have four values: None, Friends, Me only, or Public.

I think this is either a huge oversight in the API or I cannot find out how to implement what I think is the right way to do this. For example, if I am a user of Spotify, I want to Add to Timeline but I want those stories to be visible to certain lists. In the Activity Log (which is private to me) I can control the visibility of all the previous posts from Apps and their visibility in terms of lists, but not for these new Timeline updates from Spotify. I tried going back to some activities posted by YouTube and I can control which lists its visible for in the dropdown on the right during hover.

I want to give the users of my App the option to control which lists their actions show to by default. The new API seems to have taken a feature away because I can't see where that control is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can control who can see Timeline activity on a per app basis directly from the new authentication dialog (See the control next to: **This activity is visible to:**)  This setting includes Friend Lists.  You can also guide your app users to change this setting at any time by going to their App Settings on Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications), and setting the visibility of **App activity privacy:** for your application.